# How do you wait for a Network Stream to have data to read?

Tags: c#, multithreading, networkstream

I have a worker thread in my application that is responsible for three different things. Requests for two of the jobs turn up in Queues that I have written, the other job is activated when a request turns up on a Network stream. I would like my worker thread to wait when there is no work to be done. This is easy with the two Queues as they expose a ManualResetEvent that is set when they have items, however the NetworkStream does not seem to have this. The NetworkStream has been retrieved from a TcpClient.

What I am after is code that looks something like this:

```
while (notDone)
{
    WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[] { queue1.HasData, queue2.HasData, netStream.HasData } );
    // ...
    if (netStream.DataAvailable)
    {
        netStream.Read(buffer, 0, 20);
        // process buffer
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a way to get a WaitHandle that is set when a NetworkStream has data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the async methods of the NetworkStream and set a ManualResetEvent in the EndReceive method.

```
// ...
netStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, callback, state);
// ...
```

inside the callback method

```
netStream.EndRead(ar);
netStreamManualResetEvent.Set();
```

then your code

```
while (notDone)
{
    WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[] { queue1.HasData, queue2.HasData, netStreamManualResetEvent} );
    // ...
    if (netStream.DataAvailable)
    {
        // make the buffer from the AsyncState in the callback method available here
        // process buffer
    }
}
```

Comment: If the remote host shuts down the connection and there is no more data available 0 bytes will be read. Why do you ask?

Comment: If you can't make BeginRead read zero bytes you start having to manage the read buffer between the main loop and the call back. This is totally doable but is not as nice as I would like.

Comment: Not necessarily because the buffer will remain untouched (by the stream) until you call BeginRead again after the call to EndRead in the callback, this means that you can manage the buffer with well placed calls to BeginRead and EndRead for example not calling BeginRead again in the callback instead call it again after the process buffer code

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is probably to use an additional thread which reads synchronously and puts extra data onto an extra queue.

Alternatively you could use asynchronous IO, but that's somewhat tricky - and you'd still need to have some additional queue.

Although `Socket` has a `Select()` method (and you can get at a socket from a `NetworkStream`) I don't believe it exposes this functionality in a way which lets you mix it with other kinds of wait handles.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered, that if you call `NetworkStream.Read` with `size = 0`, it will actually block:

```
networkstream.Read(buffer, 0, 0);
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read?view=netframework-4.8) is not clear about this, but for me it worked.

Comment: this is the exact answer. I went is search of a better way, but in the end we both had the same idea, and it works well for most cases for getting ANY data.