# Stream reading with await async

Tags: c#

I have written the following method to read data from a stream in general. On my computer it's gonna be a MemoryStream, and in the real world, it's gonna be a network stream.

```
    public async void ReadAsync()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int numBytesRead = await _stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, 1024);

        // Process data ...

        // Read again.
        ReadAsync();
    }
```

The idea here is that data gets processed in the callback, and the callback should then spawn a new reader-thread (and kill the old).
This does not happen however. I get a StackOverflowException.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got a never-ending [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

You're calling `ReadAsync()` forever and never return from the method (hence breaking the infinite recursion).

A possible solution is:

```
public async void ReadAsync()
{
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int numBytesRead = await _stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, 1024);

    // Process data ...

    // Read again.
    if(numBytesRead > 0)
    {
        ReadAsync();
    }
}
```

To understand recursion better, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264982/39106).

Comment: Isn't execution halted at the await, and the remainder of the method used as a callback? Hence ReadAsync is called in the callback. If numBytesRead is 0, then I will never be able to read more of the stream. I want to keep listening for incoming data.

Comment: @lejon, It's a continuation block, yes. When the Task is finished you will return to after the await part. But then you'll call "`ReadAsync`" immediately again. If `numBytesRead` is zero, you've got nothing stopping you from trying to Read again. Makes sense? If you want to wait for incoming data over the network, that's another question.

Comment: Yes. That makes perfect sense. Thanks for pointing that out. How would I go about waiting for incoming data, then?

Comment: No problem. Check this out regarding how to wait for data when it comes ti `NetworkStream`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361714/how-do-you-wait-for-a-network-stream-to-have-data-to-read

Comment: Wouldn't it overflow on large data transfers anyway?

Answer (score 8):

There are no threads directly involved here (see my intro to `async`/`await`).

Your `StackOverflowException` is caused (as it usually is) by recursion that goes too deep. Just re-write the method to be iterative:

```
public async Task ReadAsync()
{
  byte[] data = new byte[1024];

  while (true)
  {
    int numBytesRead = await _stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, 1024);
    if (numBytesRead == 0)
      return;

    // Process data ...
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not anymore async now if it's like that, no?

Comment: @Frederic: Not sure what you mean. It is still `async`, as the method signature clearly shows.

Answer (score 3):

You need at least to check if there is a data in stream, to repeat operation or your recursion never stops

```
// Read again.
if(numBytesRead != 0)
    ReadAsync();
```