# Massive time delay after socket disconnect in Async/Await TCP server

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, async-await

I've been upgrading some older software from the Begin/End pattern in C# to use the new `async` functionality of the `TcpClient` class.

Long story short, this receive method works great for small numbers of connected sockets, and continues to work great for 10,000+ connections.  The problem comes when these sockets disconnect.

The method I am using server side is, in essence, this (heavily simplified but still causes the problem):

```
private async void ReceiveDataUntilStopped(object state)
        {
            while (IsConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[8192];
                    int recvCount = await _stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                    if (recvCount == 0) { throw new Exception(); }
                    Array.Resize(ref data, recvCount);
                    Console.WriteLine(">>{0}<<", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
                }
                catch { Shutdown(); return; }
            }
        }
```

This method is called using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ReceiveDataUntilStopped);` when the connection is accepted.

To test the server, I connect 1,000 sockets.  The time it takes to accept these is neglible, around 2 seconds or so.  I'm very pleased with this.  However, when I disconnect these 1,000 sockets, the process takes a substantial amount of time, 15 or more seconds, to handle the closure of these sockets (the `Shutdown` method).  During this time, my server refuses any more connections.    I emptied the contents of the Shutdown method to see if there was something in there blocking, but the delay remains the same.

Am I being stupid and doing something I shouldn't?  I'm relatively new to the async/await pattern, but enjoying it so far.

Is this unavoidable behaviour?  I understand it's unlikely in production that 1,000 sockets will disconnect at the same time, but I'd like to be able to handle a scenario like this without causing a denial of service.  It strikes me as odd that the listener stops accepting new sockets, but I expect this is because all the ThreadPool threads are busy shutting down the disconnected sockets?

EDIT: While I agree that throwing an exception when 0 bytes are received is not good control flow, this is **not** the source of the problem.  The problem is still present with simply `if (recvCount == 0) { Shutdown(); return; }`.  This is because `ReadAsync` throws an `IOException` if the other side disconnects uncleanly.  I'm also aware that I'm not handling the buffers properly etc. this is just an example, with minimal content, just like SO likes.  I use the following code to accept clients:

```
private async void AcceptClientsUntilStopped()
        {
            while (IsListening)
            {
                try
                {
                    ServerConnection newConnection = new ServerConnection(await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync());
                    lock (_connections) { _connections.Add(newConnection); }
                    Console.WriteLine(_connections.Count);
                }
                catch { Stop(); }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens if the socket closes during `ReadAsync`? (I'm assuming `NetworkStream`?) Will it exit / throw directly or wait for some sort of timeout? If you haven't already I'd recommend you to read up on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx, especially the part on blocking / non-blocking sockets.

Comment: It throws (or returns 0, if clean). Already had a look at MSDN for NetworkStream. I know `Sockets` don't behave like this, I'm fairly sure I'm doing something wrong with the threading compared to the networking really...

Comment: What does the `ShutDown` method do and look like, could you please share it?

Comment: It seems to be irrelevant.  The problem persists even when Shutdown is empty.  This was the first thing I checked, so I can confirm that Shutdown is not blocking at all.

Comment: Additionally, this is an `async void`! And why is the `_stream` instance in the class scope -- best not to keep that around like that, especially in an `async` context.

Comment: It's void because I'm not interested in the result.  Why is having stream in class scope bad?  The client is also in class scope.  I make sure to dispose of both appropriately.

Comment: When you do `async void` the async state machine doesn't know how to correctly handle it, as it uses `Task` and `Task<T>`. If you do not care about the result use `Task`.  And it is not "bad" to have them in class scope, just something that stands out like a sore thumb -- you should be aware that in parallel programming anything can and will impact shared variables like that...

Comment: A return type of Task raises a warning if I don't await it.  I thought the only consequence of using void is that exceptions must be handled inside the method?  I don't see anything thread-unsafe about storing `_stream` in class scope.  What would you do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106355/discussion-between-david-pine-and-luke-park).

Comment: A client disconnecting from a server should not be treated as an exception - reading 0 bytes actually means the other side is closing its sending part of the connection, as part of the graceful disconnect procedure. As a side effect, throwing an exception does impact performance.

Comment: Why don't you use whatever is idiomatic in your language for high performance socket servers? I assume it's not something that permits the client to trigger something unduly expensive in the server -- if so, it's broken and should be fixed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This is meant to be the "new" way of doing exactly that.  I've solved the problem now but there is definitely a performance cost.  I'm thinking about going back to the old way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (recvCount == 0) { throw new Exception(); }`

In case of disconnect you throw an exception. Exceptions are very expensive. I benchmarked them once at 10000/sec. This is very slow.

Under the debugger, exceptions are vastly slower again (maybe 100x).

This is a misuse of exceptions for control flow. From a code quality standpoint this is really bad. Your exception handling also is really bad because it catches too much. You *meant* to catch socket problems but you're also swallowing all possible bugs such as NRE.

```
        using (mySocket) { //whatever you are using, maybe a TcpClient
        while (true)
        {
                byte[] data = new byte[8192];
                int recvCount = await _stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                if (recvCount == 0) break;
                Array.Resize(ref data, recvCount);
                Console.WriteLine(">>{0}<<", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
        }
        Shutdown();
        }
```

Much better, wow.

Further issues: Inefficient buffer handling, broken UTF8 decoding (can't split UTF8 at any byte position!), usage of async void (probably, you should use `Task.Run` to initiate this method, or simply call it and discard the result task).

---

In the comments we discovered that the following works:

Start a high-prio thread and accept synchronously on that (no await). That should keep the accepting going. Fixing the exceptions is not going to be 100% possible, but: await increases the cost of exceptions because it rethrows them. It uses `ExceptionDispatchInfo` for that which holds a **process-global lock** while doing that. Might be part of your scalability problems. You could improve perf by doing await `readTask.ContinueWith(_ => { })`. That way await will never throw.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This does indeed solve for when the other side disconnects cleanly.  See my edit above.  I need to catch exceptions in this method as they can't be handled externally (due to async void).  Also, I need to be able to account for unclean disconnects, where `ReadAsync` throws an `IOException`.

Comment: OK, just catch them and do what you want with them. You probably should catch `SocketException` then. Since this does not fix the problem we need to investigate further. How do you disconnect? Cleanly or uncleanly? Post the code that accepts connections (since you say that it stops doing that).

Comment: I think the problem might be that all my ThreadPool threads get bogged down working on 1,000 IOExceptions at the same time.  Posted the accepting code above.  I've tested using clean and unclean disconnects.  The clean works fine, the unclean still causes the problem.

Comment: That's strong evidence of my exception theory. What does `new ServerConnection` do? A possible fix would be to accept synchronously on a high-priority thread. Async IO for accepting does not help in any way.

Comment: I 100% agree it's caused by Exceptions.  It's solving the problem that is hard.  The only thing `new ServerConnection` does other than initializing variables is `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ReceiveDataUntilStopped);`.  This speeds the connection process up quite a bit.  I think we know what the problem is but I have no idea how to fix it.  I have to catch the exceptions and that is whats slowing it down.

Comment: OK, start a high-prio thread and accept synchronously on that (no await). That should keep the accepting going. Fixing the exceptions is not going to be 100% possible, but: await increases the cost of exceptions because it rethrows them. It uses `ExceptionDispatchInfo` for that which holds a process-global lock while doing that. Might be part of your scalability problems. You could improve perf by doing `await readTask.ContinueWith(_ => { })`. That way await will never throw.

Comment: Ok I'll try doing both those things and get back to you.

Comment: Just adding the `ContinueWith` and then checking `IsFaulted` reduced the delay dramatically, to around 0.25-0.5 of a second.  Excellent!  If you want to edit your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Man, I should start charging for my advice :) This is quite advanced knowledge.

Comment: You might even be able to get one of those fancy "jobs" that everyone talks about. Heh

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided and my initial understanding of the problem. I think that there are several things that you should do to address this issue.

1. Use `async Task` instead of `async void`. This will ensure that the `async` state machine knows how to actually maintain its state.
2. Instead of invoking `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ReceiveDataUntilStopped);` call  `ReceiveDataUntilStopped` via `await ReceiveDataUntilStopped` in the context of an `async Task` method.

With `async` `await`, the `Task` and `Task<T>` objects represent the asynchronous operation. If you are concerned that the results of the `await` are executed on the original calling thread you could use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to prevent capturing the current synchronization context. This is explained very well [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [here too](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Additionally, look at how a similar "read-while" was written [with this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264946/stream-reading-with-await-async).