# How to wait on input from two sources?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I've got a `TcpClient` that I'm reading data from using its `NetworkStream`.  Right now, I'm able to read like so:

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, ((int)socket.ReceiveBufferSize));
```

But I'd like to be able to receive input from two different places, either from the socket or from a `BlockingCollection`, and respond to either one.  Now if this was native Winapi code, I'd use [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to wait on whichever one delivers something first.  It appears that the .NET equivalent is [`WaitHandle.WaitAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but neither `TcpClient`, nor `BlockingCollection` appear to have a WaitHandle to wait on!  `NetworkStream` has a method that creates one, but it's marked as obsolete.

So what's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Could you encompass the code that performs the reading in to `Task`s and then use `Task.WaitAny`?

Comment: Have a look at the asynchronous methods, i.e. either `ReadAsync` (newer, better) or `BeginRead`/`EndRead`.

Comment: [How do you wait for a Network Stream to have data to read?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361714/how-do-you-wait-for-a-network-stream-to-have-data-to-read).

Comment: Not sure if it's the "proper" way, or that I've understood your question sufficiently, but in similar situations I have two threads doing work, and they each have an AutoResetEvent associated with them. When they complete what they're doing (come out of a blocking read call for example) they Set the AutoResetEvent. The process that is waiting for the two other threads does a WaitHandle.WaitAny() on the two AutoResetEvents.